# Reading method in java with starting and ending position gone wrong

Tags: java, windows, file

So basically, I have an exam question that said "Add your directory to this method" and the follow up questions require that I use this method. My classmates that own macs, alongside with the examiner for some reason managed to get the file working.

```
public static String GetTextFromFile(int startPosition, int endPosition) {
    String gotText = "";
    String outText = "";

    try {
        Scanner fileInp = new Scanner(new File(
                "C:/Users/Ted/Desktop/diary.txt"));
        while (fileInp.hasNextLine()) {
            gotText = gotText + fileInp.nextLine();
            gotText = gotText + "\n";
        }
        // System.out.println(gotText);
        for (int i = startPosition; i <= endPosition; i = i + 1) {
            outText = outText + gotText.charAt(i - 1);
        }
        fileInp.close();
        return outText;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return outText;
    }
}
```

I'm using a windows, why does this not work for me?
This is what an error says with an input of
Starting point 1 and ending point 9

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at secretmessages.SecretMessages.GetTextFromFile(SecretMessages.java:78)
    at secretmessages.SecretMessages.EveryNthCharacterSteganography(SecretMessages.java:199)
    at secretmessages.SecretMessages.main(SecretMessages.java:322)
```

Comment: What is the value of gotText ? Did you try to print the value

Comment: It seems your `gotText.length < endpoint`

Comment: @Sanjeev value is empty string, check the exception

Comment: @Youngistan I saw that. My point is valid for that as well.

Comment: @Sanjeev I dnt say u r incorrect. I say value is empty

Answer (score 0):

if you did not get any text from your fiel then `gotText` will still be `""`, so change this line

```
 for(int i = startPosition; i <= endPosition; i = i + 1)
```

to

```
for(int i = startPosition; i <= endPosition && gotText.length () > 0; i = i + 1)
```

Also I would rather use [String.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Also log your exceptions

```
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace ();
    return outText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Issue in your code is you not check for empty string and use SrtingBuilder rather than String.check endPosition value.
>   endPosition value could not be greater than total length of string.
>   See following code may Resolve your Problem.
>
> StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("");
>   while (fileInp.hasNextLine()) {
>            sb.append(fileInp.nextLine()).append("\n");
>
> ```
>   }
>   String gotText=sb.toString();
>   // System.out.println(gotText);
>   for (int i = startPosition; i <= endPosition; i = i + 1) {
>      outText = outText + gotText.charAt(i - 1);
>  }
>
>   if(!gotText.equals("")){
>   if(endPosition > gotText.length())
>        endPosition=gotText.length()-1;
>   for (int i = startPosition; i <= endPosition; i = i + 1) {
>               outText = outText + gotText.charAt(i - 1);
>           }
>   }
> ```

Comment: What is the issue in existing code. Better if you first explain issue then proposed solution

Comment: @Youngistan : issue is he has to check for empty string and also the values passed in endPosition.

Answer (score 0):

```
outText = outText + gotText.charAt(i - 1);
```

I think here if in the beginning `i==0` then `i-1` will throw the out of bound exception. And do check the `endPosition` it should not go beyond `gotText.length()`.